# Kill process of method after a period of time .net core API

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, timer

I have a program that will call a method to validate parameters requested in my API

```
public virtual IActionResult ValidatefieldPost([FromBody]Validatefield body)
        {
            dynamic ValidateFields = body.ValidateFields();

            string exampleJson = null;  
            exampleJson = "{\n  \"updateMessage\" : \"Common Field was validated.\"\n}";

            var example = exampleJson != null
            ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Successful>(exampleJson)
            : default(Successful);
            if (body.isSuccess)
            {

                    return Ok("Validate is successfull");


            }
            else
            {
                        return BadRequest(ValidateFields);
            }
        }
```

I want to set a timer for like "15 seconds" in the process of

**Validatefieds=body.Validatefields();**

so that when the process reached 15 seconds, it will replied as **"Time -out"** but when the process of the method is finished and within the time limit, it will replied as **success**. May i know if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just wrap your work in a 'Task' and wait for that to finish like so:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public virtual IActionResult ValidatefieldPost([FromBody]Validatefield body, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            object ValidateFields = null;
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            object result = null;
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                result = body.ValidateFields();
            }, cts.Token);

            task.Wait(15000, cancellationToken); // 15 seconds timeout

            if (result == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out");  // do whatever
                cts.Cancel(); // to cancel the work inside your validation, might want to pass the CT down the stack
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Has result"); // do whatever
            }
    }
```

Note how we wire into the `CancellationToken` passed down the ASP .Net Core pipeline so that you're not bogging down the resources with long waits.